# Xcode - Product Archive file xcarchive is too large

Tags: xcode, deployment, app-store, archive

I am deploying an app that has about 10 library dependencies (I am using cocoapods) and a 30MB download size on appstore, but when I archive the product for Appstore upload, the xcarchive file has about 600MB size, which takes a lot of time to upload.

If I use check the Show package contents, the folders that occupy the most are:

- dSYMs - 90MB
- Products (my app) - 333MB (215MB from Frameworks)
- SwiftSupport - 161MB

Can anything be done about the size of this archive?

Comment: Have you found any answer? Why the iPA size is too much?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when am archiving the build with image assets which its (50 MB). At that time my iPA size is 150 MB.

But when I remove all the image assets from the project and then archive the build. I shocked my iPA size is 12 MB. So basically it's because of your image assets. Please check your image assets and see which image is increasing your app size.